# Cakephp Containable query with a condition AND model hasMany with also a condition

Tags: php, cakephp, has-many

I'm here to ask a question related to the *CakePhp* engine.
I was just coding when I asked myself this :

I have a `Customer` model that hasMany Address BUT with 2 alias (one for `Address.type = "l"` and one for `Address.type = "f"`)

Everything works fine, but let's suppose I want to make a special query that get me all the Customer data and the two related Address WITH a filter for each alias.

**What  should I do ?**

Because when I'm making the query it's like the first condition (the one in the alias) is discard and the only one working is the last one.

`Customer` model

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'AddressB' => array(
        'className' => 'Address',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => array("AddressB.type" => "f"),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'AddressD' => array(
        'className' => 'Address',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => array("AddressD.type" => "l"),
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

And then my query : (also in the Customer model)

```
    $d = $this->find("all", array(
        "conditions" => array(
            "id" => $customer_id
        ),
        "contain" => array(
            "AddressD" => array(
                "conditions" => array("active" => true),
                "Cp"
            ),
            "AddressB" => array(
                "conditions" => array("active" => true),
                "Cp"
            )
        )
            )
    );
```

Comment: You are using same foreign Key for both. May i know why ? it will always return result with last relationship because of foreign key.

Comment: The foreign key is the same for the 2 alias. I just wanted to separate the Bill Address of the Delivery Address

Comment: it is unnecessary to make new relation. you can add this condition on find method instead of creating new relation

Comment: I know that, it's just I need these 2 aliases all along the Controllers and I don't want to make a special query each time. This don't need to be changed. I just want to know if its possible and I have the feeling that it is.